# Font style doesn't work in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

The font Arizonia doesn't work in Firefox, I tried a lot, set gfx.downloadable_fonts.enabled to false and more, and now I'm asking for help.

I'm using this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'arizonia';
  src: url(arizonia-regular.woff)format('woff');
  src: url(arizonia-regular.ttf)format('truetype'); 
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal;
}
```

In every browser it works fine, but in FF. I added the code from google fonts to my site, copied the files to my rootfolder en loaded the css files in DW. It looks a bit ribbed in FF.

Comment: are you running the site locally?

Comment: Yes, I do run it locally

Comment: Have you tried setting security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541885/firefox-webfonts-not-loading

Answer (score 1):

**In case you are running the site locally:**

You might need to open `about:config` and set `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` to **false**.

After this local documents have access to all other local documents, including directory listings.

ref: [CSS @font-face not working with Firefox, but working with Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, tried all of them but it doesn't seem to work. The font style is there (in Firefox), but it looks ribbed. But I keep trying till' I got this

Answer (score 0):

According to [Firefox webfonts not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541885/firefox-webfonts-not-loading) try `font-family: arizonia;` without the quotes.