# less styles in chrome vs firefox

Tags: css, frontend, ascx

I have been trying to solve this for quite awhile now with no success, so any help would be appreciated.

In firefox 34 all my fonts, spacing and styling are perfect. In Chrome 39, it is not recognizing my fonts along with alignCenter, alignLeft and other classes.

**My styles.less file has the following at the top:**

```
@homizioBlack: 'homizio-black';

@homizioMedium: 'homizio-medium';

@homizioLight: 'homizio-light';


**My fonts.css has the following:**

@font-face{
  font-family: 'homizio-black';
  src: url('Homizio-black.ttf') format('truetype');
      }

@font-face{
  font-family: 'homizio-medium';
  src: url('Homizio-medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face{
  font-family: 'homizio-light';
  src: url('Homizio-light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

I have all of the fonts downloaded locally. 
I can inspect the element in chrome and see that it is finding my stylesheet however the font is not homizio, it is rendering as times new roman which is nowhere to be found in my code. My ascx page references all of the fonts in my fonts.css. 
Do i have to make a specific adjustment for Chrome? IE is not finding them either.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051826/font-face-with-wrong-mime-type-in-chrome) may help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox webfonts not loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541885/firefox-webfonts-not-loading)

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf: Partial support in IE9 refers to the fonts only working when set to be "installable".

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the Homizio font in chrome and I.E. I created a blank html page, and referenced the same homizio font. Still works in fF and not in chrome. other fonts i downloaded with the same tile type (ttf) work just fine.